# select multiple in dropdown

Tags: php, html

```
<label>Personal Skills</label>
                                    
<select multiple size=14 input type="text" id="skill1" name="skill1" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $out['skill1'];?>">
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select...</option>                                            
  <option value='=COMPASSIONATE'>COMPASSIONATE</option>
  <option value='EFFECTIVE COMMUNICATOR'>EFFECTIVE COMMUNICATOR</option>
  <option value='LEADERSHIP'>LEADERSHIP</option>
  <option value='INSIGHTFUL'>INSIGHTFUL</option>
  <option value='PERCEPTIVE'>PERCEPTIVE</option>
  <option value='CREATIVE'>CREATIVE</option>
  <option value='FLEXIBLE'>FLEXIBLE</option>
  <option value='INNOVATIVE'>INNOVATIVE</option>
  <option value='LOGICAL THINKING'>LOGICAL THINKING</option>
  <option value='PROBLEM SOLVING'>PROBLEM SOLVING</option>
  <option value='SOCIABLE'>SOCIABLE</option>
  <option value='CONSISTENT'>CONSISTENT</option>
  <option value='MARKETING'>MARKETING</option>
  <option value='CRITICAL THINKING '>CRITICAL THINKING</option>  
  </select>
```

what is wrong in this code?we could not select multiple options

Comment: You can hold down the Ctrl or Shift keys to select multiple items. Nothing is wrong as far as I can see except that a `select` should not have a `value` attribute directly - its value comes from whatever options are selected.

Comment: i what to select multiple options without holding ctrl or shift keys

Comment: Well that's not how it works, sorry. Talk to the people who make browsers, and create usability specficiations, if you want to change that. There's nothing you can do about it. And if you tried to do it differently, it would just confuse your users, who are used to things working in a certain way in other applications.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works well as it is, although there is something you put by fault as I think in the **select** tag you put **input type="text"** it may cause the problem you are facing